# Default timeout for HttpComponent Client

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I can't find any documentation on the default httpParams for httpclient 4.1 ?

What's the default socket timeout when I do a GET ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html), the `http.socket.timeout` parameter controls the SO_TIMEOUT value, and:

> If this parameter is not set, read operations will not time out
>   (infinite timeout).

Comment: This setting is changed from 4.3.X version. Default is system timeout.

Comment: @Chandru What do you mean by system time out?

Comment: @Sam See my answer below. system default timeout is TCP timeout set for the machine (if any) and vary by OS. In mac it is 60secs

Comment: @Chandru thanks for the answer. And can pls tell how to get what tcp timeout set?

Answer (score 29):

The accepted answer is not applicable for newer versions of HttpClient. Versions 4.3.X and above use the system default which is usually 60 secs.

Taken from HttpClient javadoc.

```
public int getSocketTimeout()
Defines the socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds, which is the timeout for waiting for data or, put differently, a maximum period inactivity between two consecutive data packets).
A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default).

Default: -1
```

Comment: How can I get the system default?

Answer (score 10):

For Apache HttpClient version 4.x upwards

```
int timeout = 5*60; // seconds (5 minutes)
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
      .setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000)
      .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout * 1000)
      .setSocketTimeout(timeout * 1000).build();
HttpClient httpClient = 
   HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm observing infinite timeout. I'm using httpclient 4.5.13 which in turn uses httpcore 4.4.13 where SocketConfig class defines default 0 (no timeout). https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/config/SocketConfig.html#getSoTimeout()

Comment: I'm observing infinite timeout  on version 4.5

Answer (score 1):

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html#getSocketTimeout%28%29

A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default).

Default: -1